# Creating custom JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am having the below JSON object.

```
"Department": [
      {
        "depType": "Testing",
        "name": "xyz",
        "address":""
      },
      {
        "deptype": "Developer",
        "name": "abc"
      }
    ]
```

I want to create another object based on the type of deptartment (depType). Something like this

```
"Testing":{
        "name": "xyz",
        "address":""
        },
"Developer":{
        "name": "abc"
        }
```

With the help of Object.keys, I was able to get the keys

Comment: It's not clear what is being asked? What problem are you struggling with?

Comment: @Tom Grant How to create a new object based on depType?

Comment: You want to check the depType on the first object, to then create another object containing what?

Comment: if depType = Testing then object should be formed lik this "Testing":{
        "name": "xyz",
        "address":""
        }

Comment: Problem definition not clear

Comment: @Amol Tate Wat is not clear in this?

Comment: which language you are using and what you want to do and you are not mentioned any code sample that you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You had some Property-naming issues with camelCased `"depType"`. Fix that.
- Create a new copy of the desired object to manipulate using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(orgObj))`
- Loop that object to find the desired Property `"Department"`
- Since Department is an Array of Objects you need to loop that Array `for(var i=0; i<dep.length; i++)`.
- Than you'll need to match if that Array contains `arrObj.hasOwnProperty( "depType" )`
- if successful you can than fill your new object with all the info `newObj[arrObj.depType] = arrObj;`
- Since now, inside your new object there's also the good old `"depType"` property you can get rid of it using `delete`.

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/wixasa/1/edit?js,console,output)**

```
var myjson = {
  "Department": [
      {
        "depType": "Testing",   // NOTE: "camelCase"
        "name": "xyz",
        "address":""
      },
      {
        "depType": "Developer", // FIX: "camelCase" !!
        "name": "abc"
      }
    ]
};

function depTypify( orgObj ) {
  var objCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(orgObj)); // Fresh copy
  var newObj = {};
  for(var prop in objCopy){
    if(prop === "Department") {
      var dep = objCopy[prop];          // get Department Array
      for(var i=0; i<dep.length; i++) { // Loop array
        var arrObj = dep[i];            // Explore Each Array Object
        if(arrObj.hasOwnProperty( "depType" )) {
          newObj[arrObj.depType] = arrObj;
          delete arrObj.depType;        // We don't need it any more
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return newObj;
}

var myNewJson = depTypify( myjson );
```

if you do than `console.log( myNewJson )` this is what you'll get:

```
[object Object] {
  Developer: [object Object] {
    name: "abc"
  },
  Testing: [object Object] {
    address: "",
    name: "xyz"
  }
}
```

The nice thing is that your old json is still intact.